# Can an IGCSE problem be this complex?

Tags: trigonometry

Following diagram has the plan view of 4 sector-shaped tiles placed in a parallelogram-shaped box.  C and F are the midpoints of the arcs AB and OG respectively.  Length OB is given to be 10 cm.  How do we find

- angle OCF,
- length CE,
- length and breadth of the underlying box.

Four Tiles Inside a parallelogram box

[image: Four Tiles Inside a parallelogram box]]

Here's what I've tried.

First of all, I assumed that all tiles are equal.

Since C is given to be the midpoint of the arc, angle COB is 20 degrees.  Due to the above assumption (all tiles are equal), OBF also is 20 degrees.  Thus, I establish that OC and BF are parallel.

From this point onwards, things seem pretty confusing to me.  I can find line length BC, and angle OCB using sine rule.  But, I'm interested in angle OCF, which is part of OCB.  Can anyone help with this?

NOTE: This question is based on an IGCSE math problem.

Comment: I just made an edit to the question.  The radius of the sector is given as 10 cm.

Answer (score 0):

you did good on the first angle OCB is 20°

to find Length CE first find midpoint of OB Which is 5cm label it M then find length of CM
since you have Angle MOC as 20° and OCM As 20° and line OM as 5cm use the Sin A/ a= SinB/b formula to find line CM. After that find line EM use sine rule since you have angle ABO as 50° and line BM as 5cm after that subtract line CM from line EM to get CE

you can figure out the rest once you done the above part it becomes simple

Comment: How did you establish that midpoint M of OB will lie on CF too?  I mean, prove that these lines intersect at M?